# an equivalent condition on semicontinuous

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $f:[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$ be an upper semicontinuous function.Does the following two conditions equivalent?

(1)$f(t)<t$ for any $t>0$;

(2)$u\leq f(v)\Rightarrow u\leq v$,and if $s_n\to t>0$ as $n\to\infty$,then $$lim_{n\to\infty}sup f(s_n)<t.$$